# kahler einstein metric for exceptional compact type hermitian symmetric space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Can anyone write down the kahler einstein metric for exceptional compact type hermitian symmetric spaces($\frac{E_6}{SO(10)*SO(2)}$ and $\frac{E_7}{E_6*SO(2)}$).  I can find the bergmann kernel for their dual, are there anyway i can exploit this?

Comment: "Write down" in terms of what?  We know the Kähler structures explicitly in terms of their pullbacks as left-invariant tensors on the Lie groups $\mathrm{E}_6$ and $\mathrm{E}_7$.  This is just linear algebra.  I suspect, though, that you don't care for this way of "writing" them "down".

Comment: Dear Robert, what i really need is to find the volume element locally explicitly.  I guess it will be similar to the bergman kernel function for their the non-compact duals, because this is the case when we consider Grassmanians or hyperquadrics.  Do you know  any results about this?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'find the volume element locally explicitly'. 'Explicitly' in terms of what? It is explicit *globally* as a left-invariant 32-form on $\mathrm{E}_6$ or a 54-form on $\mathrm{E}_7$, but that's trivial and surely not what you are trying to get.  What about this: Take the standard embedding of $E_6$ into $\mathrm{SU}(27)$, as the subgroup that preserves Cartan's cubic $P$. Then the $16$-dimensional exceptional HSS $X$ is the singular locus of the hypersurface $P=0$ in $\mathbb{CP}^{26}$, and the metric on $X$ is just the restriction of the Fubini-Study metric to $X$.

Comment: Thanks! that's kind of what i am looking for!  I want to write down the volume form in terms of local coordinates$z_1,z_2,...,z_{16}$  What about $E_7$ case?  How to embed it into $CP^{55}$?

Comment: Well, for the $E_7$ case, you write down Cartan's homogeneous quartic polynomial $Q$ in $56$ variables (this gives an embedding of $E_7$ into $\mathrm{Sp}(28)\subset \mathrm{SU}(56)$), and then you look at the singular locus $Y$ of the projectivized hypersurface $Q = 0$ in $\mathbb{CP}^{55}$, which turns out to be a smooth projective variety of dimension $27$.  Then the Kähler-Einstein metric on $Y$ that is invariant under $E_7$ is just the restriction of the Fubini-Study metric on $\mathbb{CP}^{55}$ to $Y$.

Comment: Dear Professor, Do you know what is the explicit form of Cartan's cubic and Cartan's quartic?

Comment: Yes, I do.  You can find these formulae in Cartan's paper on the real forms of the complex simple Lie groups (I don't have the exact reference with me right now, though).  When I have time, I can enter them explicitly.  They are not that complicated.